# Регистрация, авторизация, хеширование паролей на Spring

Tags: spring, oauth

Интересна эта тема. Тема регистрации, авторизации, хеширования паролей. Что лучше использовать? Или что чаще используют на продакшене? Знаю что в 5 спринге появился bcriptencoder и о нем неоднозначные отзывы. Знаю что есть oauth2, и возможности сервлетов. Но что лучше? Просветите пожалуйста на эту тему. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Что лучше в какой ситуации? У вас что за задача?

Comment: @RomanDanilov задача понять, что щюпать первым. И пропустить то что лучше и использовать изза сложности и старости технологии. А также узнать что используют чаще)